# ConfReg library using randomForest

Tags: r, random-forest, confidence-interval

I am attempting to use the `confReg` package to obtain a conf Interval C.I. for a `randomForest` Model I have developed. I have tried the examples and they ran without a problem.

When I try to use the `selectFeatures` method on my model I receive errors for each column in the training dataset.

Errors look like:

```
<simpleError in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object '213' not found>
<simpleError in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object '213' not found>
<simpleError in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object '213' not found>
<simpleError in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object '2' not found>
<simpleError in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object '2' not found>
<simpleError in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object '2' not found>
<simpleError in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object '2' not found>
<simpleError in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object '2' not found>
```

I do get back a `featureList` and try to run the `learnFromDataset` which I also get an error:

```
> rModel <- learnFromDataset(rModel,traningData)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '1' not found
```

I hope to evaluate the model and get a C.I. does anyone have experience with this library? I can supply a full set of code that I am running if needed, but it will look the example in the package with my dataset instead of a made up one and I use `randomForest` as the model...

Thank You in advance.

R 3.0.2 64 bit on windows 8.

Richard

Comment: I do not believe that the confReg package supports random forest model objects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't see randomForest or many other platforms mentioned in the help. The library is mentioned in a paper the author has done for conf intervals in QSAR. Most of my QSAR work has been done with ranadomForest. I could try SVM or lm or some other supported model to see what I get for a CI. In the help file in section 3 Model Creation the last line of the first paragraph. States that "the regression object can be created with any regression method that uses a formula as input..." randomForest does a formula as input. I will keep trying options to see.. thanks.